# jQuery get below element

Tags: jquery

I need to retrieve the element with specific class which is placed below in DOM. For example:

```
<div>
    <a onclick="someMethod(this)">
</div>
<div class="specificClass">
</div>
```

In someMethod I have the anchor but need to retrieve the first element with class "specificClass" which is placed below.

**Update.** The position of `<div class="specificClass">` is not specified. The only thing I know - it is placed below

Comment: I have figured out a way to do it with a working [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/reKwQ/1/). See my answer below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/reKwQ/1/

Instead of using the `onclick` attribute, give your anchor a class or ID:

```
<div>
    <a class="someClass">
</div>
<div class="specificClass"></div>
```

Then bind a click event to it using jQuery and go from there:

```
$('a.someClass').click(function() {
    var $elements = $('a.someClass, .specificClass');

    var foundThis = false,
        $nextSpecificClass = null,
        $this = $(this);

    $elements.each(function() {
        var $element = $(this);
        if (foundThis === false && $element[0] == $this[0]) {
            foundThis = true;
        } else if (foundThis === true && $element.is('.specificClass')) {
            $nextSpecificClass = $element;
            return false;
        }
    });

    // Do something  with $nextSpecificClass here

    return false;
});
```

This works because you have a list of matched elements containing both the anchor and target elements, that will be in the order of discovery.

Once we find the thing we clicked on, we can accept the next available `.specificClass` element as our result.

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/reKwQ/1/

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
$('a[onclick]').parent().next('.specificClass')
```

Comment: the position of <div class="specificClass"> is not determined - so I can't use parent()

Comment: @idsa: Is there any consistency in the markup in the first place? It is hard to answer without seeing your code (other than the one you have posted in your question). The selector I have posted should work fine if you have markup like you have posted in your question. In other cases, all I can say is that you should check out `find` and/or `nextuntil` methods: http://api.jquery.com/nextUntil/

Answer (score 0):

Use [`next`](http://api.jquery.com/next/) to get the next sibling

```
function someMethod(e)
{
    // if the element is bellow you don't need to specify the selector
    var specificClass = $(e).parent().next(".specificClass");
}
```

Syntax:

```
.next( [selector] )
```

Comment: You can also add a selector: var specificClass = $(e).parent().next(".specificClass");

Comment: -1 he want's to search for the next element of a specific class. this will just return the next element with a var name of specificClass

Comment: @seth for his `html` example the selector is irrelevant

Comment: for his specific first statement "I need to retrieve the element with **specific class** which is placed below in DOM," it's obvious though. can't rely on examples alone

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way. Takes a half DOM API, half jQuery approach.

```
function someMethod(el) {
    var result;
    while( (el = el.parentNode) && !(result = $(el).next('.specificClass')).length ) {}
    alert( result.attr('class') );
}
```

Or a more jQuery way:

```
function someMethod(el) {
    var result = $(el).parents().next('.specificClass').first();
    alert( result.attr('class') );
}
```

The first will be more efficient (I'm certain), but the second is shorter and more expressive.